# Selected Device Incompatible - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-min-sdk

I have fixed this problem before but I can't now and I need a permanent fix. Everything has been going fine in Android Studio when it comes to testing my app. I now run into the problem "The selected device is incompatible." when I go to run the app. I'd like to know how I can keep it from reading my phone's API as 1 rather than changing my minSDK to cater to this problem, if possible.

EDIT: Literally just found a fix, not sure if it is permanent. I just restored my defaults in Development Options, turned USB Debugging off and on again and that did the trick.

Comment: Which OS do you have? Most of the time is a permission issue (phone or OS).

Comment: I have a Lg G3 (D850) running some custom ROM that's Android 5

Comment: I meant yout computer's OS.

Comment: Ahhhhh, okay. I'm on Windows 10

Comment: I had same issue on a new phone.  What worked for me was to turn off USB debugging, re-boot the device and then turn USB debugging back on again.

Comment: The off-on debugging suggestion didn't work for me. It kept showing the device as offline. But I was able to make it work using adb via wireless.

Answer (score 8):

All I had to do was turn off USB debugging, then turn it back on and it worked immediately. I didn't have to reboot or change any other settings.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this helps. I had a similar issue using my MotoG 2nd generation with Android Studio on Ubuntu. I switched the settings as how my phone was connected from MTP to PTP. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue,

Usually whenever I connect the android device for usb debugging, the device will prompt me asking for the permission from to access from the development PC

[image]

In my case, for some reason, I didnt get this prompt and hence, I got this error. I have turned off developer options & USB debugging, turned on again. Then, I got the prompt and the issue is solved